# How to re index only one specific wordpress post after making changes

Tags: wordpress, post

I have made some changes to an old wordpress post , which is currently indexed on google front page.

Now I am hoping to climb up the ladder with the new changes made to the post.

How do I ask google to reindex (update) only this specific old post with the new changes that has been made and not the entire site.

I have tried the FETCH option on other pages earlier, but it seems to create a duplicate entry rather than update the existing result.

Please help me with your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might take sometime but you really don't have to do anything. Once your post gets crawled again your changes will be noted.

Easiest way to speed things up would be to submit a sitemap in Google Search Console. There are a number of sitemap plug-ins available for WordPress.

Also, having a few new links to the post or social media shares should help as well.